# Dividing the values of X-axis in Kibana-4

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

I have my X-axis,with numbers ranging from 100-1000. So while visualising I would like the numbers to be divided by 100 and then visualise it. Is there any way to do this in Kibana-4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right there below the Xaxis aggregation,as shown in the screenshot below,there is an "Advanced" option(red box 1),where you can find "JSON input" field(red box 2).
[image]

There at the "JSON input" field you can add the following script and achieve the division of values displayed in X axis.

```
{"script":"(_value)/100"}
```

A more detailed explanation for this can be found in the official elasticsearch blog :https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-2-get-now/

Comment: Just a FYI, this suggestion does require scripting be enabled which is not on by default